# Using loop.run_in_executor to call sync functions from async ones

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have 3 functions: `func_1`, `func_2`, and `func_3`. I would like to run these asynchronously, so that I do not have to wait for `func_1` to finish before `func_2` starts executing.

The problem is, that the definition of `func_1` for example looks something like this:

```py
async def func_1(a, b):
    x = some_sync_func(a)
    y = some_other_sync_func(b)
    z = another_sync_func(x, y)
    return yet_another_sync_func(z)
```

The functions that I am calling within func_1 are all synchronous functions which are non-awaitable. Thus, they will block the execution of `func_2` and `func_3`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685210/calling-sync-functions-from-async-function) that `loop.run_in_executor()` can be used to call synchronous functions from asynchronous functions without blocking the execution.
Thus, I modified the definition of `func_1` as follows:

```py
async def func_1(a, b):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    x = await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_sync_func, a)
    y = await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_other_sync_func, b)
    z = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: another_sync_func(a,b))
    w = await loop.run_in_executor(None, yet_another_sync_func, z)
    return w
```

Is this the right way to deal with this problem? Am I using `loop.run_in_executor()` correctly?
[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), the docs provide an example which seems to support this. I don't know what threads are, or what a "process pool" is, and haven't really been able to make much sense of the docs.

Comment: Seems right to me.  Be aware that Python is not very efficient at multithreading, so the gain of the change may not be as great as expected. This depends on what the synchronous functions actually do.

Comment: Yes, these awaits make sure that while the long sync functions are running, execution gets suspended to the event loop, which gets to service other tasks running at the same time. Also, consider replacing `run_in_executor` with the more modern [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread).

Comment: *I don't know what threads are, or what a "process pool" is* - threads are units of execution that run in parallel inside the your process. A thread pool is a collection of threads to which you can submit tasks that you want to run asynchronously. A process pool is like a thread pool, but giving tasks to external processes. `run_in_executor()` uses an underlying abstraction that allows thread or process pools being used. If you just pass `None` as the first argument, it will use a thread pool set up by the system by default. As mentioned in the previous comment, you can also use `to_thread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost right, but since you are awaiting eagerly at each function call, the next line of code in each case (after the await) will only be called when the line with `await` finishes execution.

However if you call `func_1` in parallel from some other place, two instances of `func_1` will work in parallel. (I am almost sure that is not what you want).

So, in order for these other functions to actually run in parallel (in other threads), you have to create the task to run each of them, but not await it immediately, instead, you gather all the tasks you want to run in parallel and await for them at once (usually with a function properly named [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) ):

```
...

async def func_1(a, b):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task_x = loop.run_in_executor(None, some_sync_func, a)
    task_y = loop.run_in_executor(None, some_other_sync_func, b)
    task_z = loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: another_sync_func(a,b))
    x, y, z = await asyncio.gather(task_x, task_y, task_z)
    # this depends on `z` so, it is not included in the gather. 
    # if its return value is not important, you can ommit the 
    # await, return the task, and await for it sometime later.
    w = await loop.run_in_executor(None, yet_another_sync_func, z)
    return w
...
```